# Валидация формы с использованием jQuery Validation

Tags: jquery

На сайте (asp.net mvc4) есть форма обратной связи, 
делаю валидацию полей формы при помощи [jQuery Validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)
Подключаю библиотеку jQuery, подключаю скрипт jquery.validate.min.js,
пишу код для валидации одного поля

```
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $("#feedback-form").on('submit', function () {
            $(this).validate({
                rules: {
                    Name: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 2
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    Name: {
                        required: "Please enter a username",
                        minlength: "Your username must consist of at least 2 characters"
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

вот сама моя форма

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Feedback", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "feedback-form" }))
{
<!-- Name -->
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, null, new { @class = "text-field" })
<a href="#" class="link1" id="submit-button" onclick="document.getElementById('feedback-form').submit()"><em><b>Send</b></em></a>
}
```

**UPD** HTML-код формы

```
<form action="/Home/Feedback" id="feedback-form" method="post">
<!-- Name -->
<a href="#" class="link1" id="submit-button" onclick="document.getElementById('feedback-form').submit()"><em><b>Send</b></em></a>
```

</form>

Никаких ошибок в консоли нет, но валидации не происходит, никаких сообщений об ошибках не выводится. В чем проблема?

Comment: Приложите сгенерированный HTML-код формы, а не серверный.

Comment: @Zhukov Roman сделано

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас инициализация плагина происходит на submit формы, а нужно до, просто вынесите её на domReady:

```
$(function (){
    $("#feedback-form").validate({
         submitHandler: function (form){
            // Обычная отправка формы
            form.submit();

            // или отправка через ajax
            $.post(form.action, $(form).serialize(), function (result, xhr){
                // форма отправлена успешно
            });
         },

        /* опции валидации */
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YrWD4/

Comment: ну на сабмит-то тоже должно работать, разве нет?

Comment: Нет, не будет, событие submit это уже факт отправления формы на сервер, так что отработает только инициализация.

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Comment: Все равно не работает. Никаких ошибок в консоли, но не работает.

Comment: Проблема в вашем html коде, вижу строчку `document.getElementById('feedback-form').submit()`. Вставьте html код на jsfiddle.net, а то тот что в вопросе побился.

Comment: Вот код http://jsfiddle.net/wvZ6n/3/ , только jquery.validate.min.js не подключен.

Comment: Поправил ваш пример http://jsfiddle.net/wvZ6n/4/

Comment: Да, большое спасибо, работает! А еще такой вопрос: место, где будет выводится сообщение об ошибки, каким-то образом задать можно?